# javascript whats worse than a carriage return?

Tags: javascript, spaces, carriage-return

```
$('#pass').focusout(function(){
    alert(($(this).text().replace(/\n\r|\n/g,'')).length);
    if(($(this).text().replace(/\n\r|\n/g,''))===''){alert('please be true');$('#water').text('enter password');}
    });
```

I'm left with a length of 3 which doesn't show up if I do:

```
alert('_'+($(this).text().replace(/\n\r|\n/g,''))+'_');
```

i see

```
alert(__);
```

even though the length is 3

these are some kind of tab spaces I think. how the hell can I remove them?

Comment: can you provide value of `$(this).text()` before replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Comment: g means global. so will replace all instead of first one

Comment: m means multiline, so replace not on first line

Answer (score 0):

You may use ([this](http://jsfiddle.net/QFeNr/))

```
replace(/\s/g,'')
```

[\s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space) matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed but don't know what your `$(this).text()` contains, so not sure about the result.

Answer (score 0):

function __kill(text){return text.replace(/\n\r|\n|\r|\t/g,'');};

\t <<<---like this